# Proper way of storing a big amount of raster data in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster

I have a folder with 5k `.ecw` raster files (14.5 GB) which I want to load to QGIS. What’s the proper way of storing those files and how to load them?

When I was using ArcMap, I created a raster catalog which was unmanaged. It allowed me to

1. Access and display the data very fast
2. Not duplicate the raster data but leave it in the original folder
3. Select the rasters by the polygons that were created

Is there something similar in QGIS?

Answer (score 3):

Try creating a [virtual raster](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rastermiscellaneous.html?highlight=build%20virtual%20raster#build-virtual-raster)

> Builds a VRT (Virtual Dataset) that is a mosaic of the list of input
> GDAL-supported rasters. With a mosaic you can merge several raster
> files.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a catalog, and then use the plugin « catalog on the fly ».